# How to populate JList with specific Strings?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am building my own calendar/planner for time management and to save daily events for personal use and I am stuck at the point where I would like to implement a specific sorting algorithm.

The idea explained below.

By Default, the JList shows all 7 weekdays. I would like to populate JList with specific items which match the search criteria.

For Example if I have a `String weekDays[] = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun"};` And a `JTextField SearchBox = new JTextField("Search");` By typing **S** in this SearchBox I would have JList Populated with 2 options - Saturday and Sunday.

Then if the `SearchBox` does not contain any search criteria, the JList shows all options from the String Array.

So the whole "Searching" thing by typing in the JTextField would automatically populate JList with the matched criteria while I am typing into it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement a custom list model, or better find an existing with Swing extension library. Check this [java jcombobox autocomplete](https://algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html)

Comment: Questions like "please do my job!!!" are not welcome here. So please try to do it by yourself. To do it please read about [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). When you have problems with using of these components, you can go back here and ask a specific question.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy If I would Ask for a set of code to fix my issue, then I would agree with you, however, I asked for any help. Like the comment bellow which mentions "DocumentListener" which I did not know about. This is the help I asked for, so if you feel like you don't want to help, you also do not need to leave a comment. ;)

Comment: @Helvijs, I suspect you would be better served actually taking the time to thank the people who have provided useful information rather then posting the unnecessary comment above. If you actually did follow the link to the "JTextField" tutorial you would find it also has an example that uses a DocumentListener to do a "search" of a text area for specific text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the whole "Searching" thing by typing in the JTextField would automatically populate JList with the matched criteria while I am typing into it.

You add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field.

An event will be generated any time a character is added or removed from the text field.

You would then  populate the JList based on the text found in the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and a working example to get you started.